# Proving that Yoneda Embedding preserves identity.

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

Here is the Yoneda embedding:

$\mathscr{C} \xrightarrow{y} \operatorname{Func}(\mathscr{C}^{op}, \mathscr{S}et)$ where $$y(f: X \to X') = (\mathscr{C}(-, f):\mathscr{C}(-, X) \to \mathscr{C}(-, X'))$$

I was trying to prove that it preserves identity but I do not know exactly what is $y(X)$ as $y$ should act on a function not a set. Could someone explain this to me please?

Comment: $y$ should be a functor. It acts on both objects and morphisms in the category. To say it preserves identities means that if you plug the identity morphism of an object $X$ of $\mathcal{C}$ into $y$, it returns the identity morphism of the object $y(X)$ of $\mathrm{Func}(\mathcal{C}^{op},Set)$.

Comment: So it is just $\mathscr{C}(-, X) $?@Thorgott

Comment: What about $1_{y(X)}$?@Thorgott

Comment: The objects of $\mathrm{Func}(\mathscr{C}^{\rm op},\mathscr{S}et)$ are functors from $\mathscr{C}^{\rm op}$ to $\mathscr{S}et$. The morphisms of this category are natural transformations between functors $\mathscr{C}^{\rm op}\to\mathscr{S}et$. $1_{y(X)}$ needs to be the identity natural transformation from $\mathscr{C}(-,X)$ to itself.

Comment: got it so it is just $1_{\mathscr{C}(-, X)},$ am I correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object $X$ is mapped to the functor $\mathscr{C}(-,X)\colon \mathscr{C}^{\rm op}\to \mathscr{S}et$ that sends objects $Y$ to the Hom-set $\mathscr{C}(Y,X)$ and sends morphisms $u\colon Y\to Z$ to the set map $\mathscr{C}(Z,X)\to\mathscr{C}(Y,X)$ obtained by "precomposition with $u$".

The embedding sends a map $f\colon X\to X'$ to the natural transformation between $\mathscr{C}(-,X)$ and $\mathscr{C}(-,X')$ that is defined by taking morphisms into $X$ and post-composing with $f$ to get morphisms into $X'$.

Thus, $\mathrm{id}_X$ is mapped to the natural transformation between $\mathscr{C}(-,X)$ and itself corresponding to "post-composition with $\mathrm{id}_X$".

Work out what that means and verify that this is indeed a natural transformation and that it is none other than the identity natural transformation.